# How to produce a filtered .net Dataset (including all JOINed tables) from a larger Dataset?

Tags: c#, linq, join, filter, dataset

I have a MySQL database of games for various systems (e.g. Playstation, Atari 2600 etc). It also holds other information such as alternative game names (for each region) and game developer etc.
This is connected via tableadapters via DataSource wizard to a strongly typed dataset `dbds`. A screenshot of some of the tables is below (taken directly from dataset designer + largely simplified – lots more tables in reality):

[image]

(I missed off the gi_system table, but you get the gist - SystemID is on `gi_game`)

This is a large dataset. I am wanting to produce an xml file that holds the data for all the relevant tables for games for **one system alone**. Then, I will import this into another app which has a dataset with the same schema. This essentially allows me to fill that dataset one system at a time. Obviously, any process will also need to export the relevant rows from other datatables into the xml files.

To export/import a dataset in its entirety is simple, of course, with `.writeXML` However, I'm puzzling over how to achieve the above.

I know I could connect the other app directly to the mysql database too, but I’m looking for an offline solution.

I have looked into Linq To Dataset (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/cross-table-queries-linq-to-dataset) but this only appears to produce a single ‘table’ of results in the query.

The other issue is, if Linq is suitable, how would I write queries given the relational structures demonstrated in the image above. I get into territory around JOIN types, which is a bit baffling. The linq for the above, if it where just game and organisation, is simple:

```
From g in gi_game

Join o in gi_organisation

On g.DeveloperID Equals o.ID

Select new {GameName = g.name, OrgName = o.name}
```

However, if I also wanted to pull in the table rows for `gi_gamealtname`, how would I write that into this query, given the parent-child relation is reversed? Also, this would have to ‘reach’ another step to pull in the relevant `gi_region` rows.]

The ultimate aim is that in the 'receiving' app, I just do GamesDataSet.ReadXML("export.xml") to load in all the games for the specific system and any associated table rows.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: I've just thought - I don't know if doing the querying on the MySQL database first is a possible solution? That is, perform a SQL query on the data before loading the dataset. Problem with this being twofold: I don't know how I would do this in code from the app-side (I know how to do a custom TableAdapter query, but now for a dataset) and also the problems remain around how to construct an SQL query solving the issues above.

Comment: Use an ORM like Entity Framework, produce an object graph in one LINQ statement with Include and serialize the whole thing.

Comment: @Gert Arnold Thanks for the reply, but I really wouldn't know where to start with that. Would I be able to apply Entity Framework to my current project (which is set up as per my OP - datasets etc)? I thought you had to design that in from the start (POCOs and all that?). Googling "object Graph" and "Include" has left me none the wiser and more confused!!

Comment: Of course we can't post an entire EF course here, but a complete working model can be generated from the database in Visual Studio. An object graph is nothing but a collection of objects with related objects. That said, I'm afraid your question is too broad for Stack Overflow.